# Is nesting of different types of inheritance allowed in hibernate.?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, inheritance

I have a situation like this...
I have four different tables namely btech_ece, btech_cse, btech_it, btech_eee all these tables have the same columns. Its just that the name differs and everything else is same. Their columns are:

- Id
- Year
- Semister
- Section
- Period
- SubjectCode
- Date
- Status

now i have four different tables under each division ece, cse, it and eee. btech_cse_1, bteh_cse_2, btech_cse_3, btech_cse_4, btech_ece_1, btech_ece_2 and so on..
the columns of these tables are like this:

- Roll_Number
- Id
- Present

the id column above is a foreign key from the tables btech_cse. My idea was that if i can use a nesting of hibernate's inheritance hierarchy. I could have a class named btech and all the classes btech_cse, btech_ece, btech_eee, btech_it can be its union-subclasses and i can have another class that says btech_cse_num which is a joined subclass of the above union subclass and each class of the form btech_cse_1 could be again a union-subclass of the btech_cse_num class. Is such nesting allowed in hibernate?

How do i best exploit the hibernate's inheritance feature to suit my situation.?

Comment: some one please help me out..........

Comment: Why are you creating your tables this way? Can you explain the rationale behind your design? I think the abstractions, based on which you are creating the tables might be wrong.

Comment: To tell you the fact, the decision of the design of the database is not in my hands, it is decided by my seniors. So i am left with little choice to work with the given database as the same database is used by couple of other people.... i am very much eagerly looking forward for the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If feasibility is the only concern, then I suggest you look at the hibernate reference documentation. The chapter on "Inheritance Mapping" gives some useful pointers, this is from version 3.3 docs:

> Hibernate does not support mixing subclass, joined-subclass and union-subclass mappings under the same root class element. It is possible to mix together the table per hierarchy and table per subclass strategies under the the same class element, by combining the subclass and join elements. It is possible to define subclass, union-subclass, and joined-subclass mappings in separate mapping documents directly beneath hibernate-mapping. This allows you to extend a class hierarchy by adding a new mapping file.